# React.JS new CSS modules

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I have been following a tutorial on React Complete Guide on Udemy, but seems like it is a bit outdated, because after ejecting files, I don't see the same code. I think it is updated today, but as a complete beginner, I have no idea how to continue my course, since I do not know how to import classes which will have unique ID's or how to enable the CSS modules to work...Thank you for your help in advance.

What he sees :
**Starting from line 162 to 169**
[This is his code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfhE9.png)

```
 test: /\.css$/,
 use: [
   require.resolve('style-loader'),
   {
     loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
     options: {
       importLoaders: 1,
       modules: true,
       localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
     },
   },
```

And what I see : 
**Starting from line 34 to 41**
[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM4jk.png)

```
// common function to get style loaders const getStyleLoaders =
(cssOptions, preProcessor) => {   const loaders = [
 require.resolve('style-loader'),
 {
   loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
   options: cssOptions,
 },
```

And what I also see is that there are new variables for `/\.css$/;` :
**Line 28 to 32**

```
// style files regexes 
const cssRegex = /\.css$/; 
const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/; 
const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/; 
const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/;
```

Comment: if this is Max's course you can message him directly and there is also a forum on udemy

Comment: Thank you, I will do this as well.

Comment: it looks like create-react-app was just updated and it now supports css-modules with out the need to eject and update the webpack. If i find a good tutorial that explains how to use them in the new configuration i will add it. once you get past that point i dont think max does much more with the webpack config and you should be all set going forward

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code

```
options: {
       importLoaders: 1,
       modules: true,
       localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
     }
```

shown above as tarting from line 162 to 169 can be added to the other field of `webpack.config.dev.js` and `webpack.config.prod.js`
Instead of `test: /\.css$/`, 
you will find cssRegex and you can add the code in that section

```
 test: cssRegex,
            exclude: cssModuleRegex,
            use: getStyleLoaders({
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: true,
              localIdentIName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
            }),
```

Comment: I also follow a tutorial on React Complete Guide on Udemy and get the same error. In my case, it works for the file "webpack.config.js" and only with one option "modules: true". The option "localIdentIName" generated error. Hope it will be useful for someone else

Answer (score 1):

For anybody, that maybe still have same issues, the best way to resolve this for me is to downgrade the react-scripts. I just make the package.json the same as the tutorial

[image]

After that, I run the setup by using `npm i --force`

Sorry, if this is not good one, but this is the best way to follow along with the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

**Replace this code from config/webpack.config.js**

```
  {
              test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
              importLoaders: 1,
              sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
              }),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true,
            },
```

**To the below code**

```
 {
      test: cssRegex,
      exclude: cssModuleRegex,
      use: getStyleLoaders({
        importLoaders: 1,
        sourceMap: isEnvProduction
            ? shouldUseSourceMap
            : isEnvDevelopment,
        modules: {
          getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
          localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
        }

      }),
      sideEffects: true,
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using react-scripts at a version higher than 1.0.X, you wouldn't need to worry about changing the webpack.
Have your css renamed to SampleName.module.css and import using "import classes from 'SampleName.module.css' " to have CSS modules enabled in your project